# changing up some code in 'DraggableViewBackground.m'

Tags: arrays, objective-c, image

Github Source URL: https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeCards

So, I need to change up some code in 'DraggableViewBackground.m'.

rather than an array of text as is on the stock source code, I need to create an array of images...

Stock section:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        [self setupView];
        exampleCardLabels = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"first",@"second",@"third",@"fourth",@"last", nil]; //%%% placeholder for card-specific information
        loadedCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        cardsLoadedIndex = 0;
        [self loadCards];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have looked at various implementations of image array, but still comes up with some errors what I can't resolve.

this is my edited code for the array:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        [self setupView];
        exampleCardGraphics = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:00_quote@2x.png, 01_quote@2x.png,02_quote@2x.png,03_quote@2x.png,04_quote@2x.png,05_quote@2x.png,06_quote@2x.png,07_quote@2x.png,08_quote@2x.png,09_quote@2x.png,10_quote@2x.png,11_quote@2x.png,12_quote@2x.png,13_quote@2x.png,14_quote@2x.png,15_quote@2x.png,16_quote@2x.png,17_quote@2x.png,18_quote@2x.png,19_quote@2x.png,20_quote@2x.png,21_quote@2x.png,22_quote@2x.png,23_quote@2x.png,24_quote@2x.png,25_quote@2x.png,26_quote@2x.png,27_quote@2x.png,28_quote@2x.png,29_quote@2x.png,30_quote@2x.png,31_quote@2x.png,32_quote@2x.png,33_quote@2x.png,34_quote@2x.png,35_quote@2x.png,36_quote@2x.png,37_quote@2x.png,38_quote@2x.png,39_quote@2x.png,40_quote@2x.png,41_quote@2x.png,42_quote@2x.png,43_quote@2x.png,44_quote@2x.png,45_quote@2x.png,46_quote@2x.png,47_quote@2x.png,48_quote@2x.png,nil]; //%%% placeholder for card-specific information
        loadedCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        cardsLoadedIndex = 0;
        [self loadCards];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I get returned "Invalid suffix '_quote' on integer constant"

How would I resolve this to get images pulled into the array, and subsequently one image for each swipe card ?

I have changed a few other things, however only instance names, which have been changed accordingly in corresponding files, so the build still succeeds but I can't get the image array to work.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: see my answer should solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a bit of a go at resolving it.. I'll comment below.